# Module code not firing

Tags: 7

I have a custom D7 module that I have placed in sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule folder. It appears on the modules page, and when I enable it, there are no errors.

The only code inside of it is:

```
function mymodule_init() {
  exit;
}

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  var_dump($form_id);exit;
}
```

Yet, neither of these cause an exit. If I place an exit outside of these functions, it definitely exits.

What is the issue?

Edit: Info file contents:

```
name = My Module
description = Form modifications for user forms (register, login).
core = 7.x
version = 7.x-1.0
dependencies[] = html5_tools
dependencies[] = elements
```

Comment: What is in the info file?

Comment: Updated with info file

Comment: The only other obvious thing would be a cache clear?

Comment: Did you try, for example, adding a call to `drupal_add_js()` in `hook_init()`? Rather than using `var_dump()`, I would use one of the debug functions present in the Devel module, such as `dsm()`.

Comment: No... I moved the module out into sites/all/modules and it started working. Can I not have it in nested folders?

Comment: Yes, you can have modules inside of folders. But they themselves need to be in a module folder. For instance, in your case. You can put the file into sites/all/modules/custom/modules/mymodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version string is wrong, and shouldn't be manually included anyway, but that wouldn't cause this issue.

[Drupal searches recursively for modules](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7). I just recreated the same set-up that you had, and after a cache clear (do this by visiting admin/config/development/performance and clicking "Clear all caches").